# Return Variable From Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to get an employees start date.  What I am trying to do is when a check box is checked make a call to the database get the date and return it into my C# code.  I think I have everything set-up close to perfect, but my call procedure returns an error.  Can someone assist me with setting up syntax so that when a check box is checked it will make a call to the database, run a stored procedure, and return the result (as a datetime) from the stored procedure back into my C# syntax?

EDIT --- The error being thrown is:
cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

```
//Calling Procedure
this.txtStartDate.Text = getHireDate(Constants.Database, employeename);

//Actual Procedure
private static string getHireDate(string Database, string employeename)
{
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Database);
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("_uspGetHireDate", connection);
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
  returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
  command.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
  connection.Open();
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();

  //This line throws an error of can not implicitly convert 'System.DateTime' to 'string'
  return Convert.ToDateTime(returnValue.Value);
}


//Stored Procedure Being Called
alter procedure [dbo].[_uspGetHireDate]
(
  @employeename varchar(100)
)

as

  declare @StartDate datetime
  set NOCOUNT ON

  Set @StartDate = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), HireDate, 101) 
                   FROM tbl_employeeinformation
                   where hiredate is not null
                   AND active = 1
                   AND employeename = @employeename

  return @StartDate
```

Comment: Why are you taking `HireDate` (which I assume is a `datetime` column) and converting it to `varchar(10)` before setting it into a `datetime` variable??

Comment: You have defined your parameter to be an Int `SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int)`. But your SP is returning string `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), HireDate, 101)`

Comment: @aSharma - actually, it's returning a `datetime` but your observation of the `SqlParameter` type is spot on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `DateTime` instead of `string` as intended in function return type

```
private static string getHireDate(string Database, string employeename)
```

{

```
----

 return Convert.ToDateTime(returnValue.Value); // Here you are returning datetime but your return type should be string as your function return type is string
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is totally messy. Why are you converting `DATE` to `VARCHAR`, then return it as an `INT`, then converting it as a `DateTime` and return as `STRING`???

First of all change your `stored procedure` to return value standard way. Return `DATE`, not `INT` with `return`:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[_uspGetHireDate]
@employeename varchar(100)
as
  set NOCOUNT ON

  SELECT HireDate
  FROM tbl_employeeinformation
  where hiredate is not null
        AND active = 1
        AND employeename = @employeename
```

Then change your method to return `DateTime`:

```
private static DateTime getHireDate(string Database, string employeename)
{
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Database);
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("_uspGetHireDate", connection);
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  connection.Open();
  var result = Convert.ToDateTime(command.ExecuteScalar());
  connection.Close();

  return result;
}
```

Thanks to @petelids for pointing this out. Change your `presentation layer` to:

```
this.txtStartDate.Text = getHireDate(Constants.Database, employeename).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

or whatever format that is appropriate. Visualizing data is a work of a `presentation layer` and not of a `business layer`. Here you are storing `connection string` in `presentation layer` and this is a bit of strange.

Also put your connections, commands etc in `using` blocks and use `try-catch` blocks.
Also I have noticed that you are not passing `@employeename` parameter to your `stored procedure`.

Comment: One small addition, if you change the return type of `getHireDate` (which I agree you should (+1)) will you need to change the assignment on the textbox - e.g. `this.txtStartDate.Text = getHireDate(Constants.Database, employeename).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: @petelids, of course it is such obvious, business should provide data and it is up to presentation how to show this data.

Comment: I completely agree, I just thought with the confusion over types in the question it was worth pointing out the conversion error will move to the textbox assignment.